# What is way to check weather object of class is assigned an instance of class or not in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I've put just small snippet of large code to explain my question:

```
class A 
{
    B b= new B();
    B z; 
    void xyz(){
        if(// condition to check z is not assigned instance of class B){
        z=b;
        }
        else{
        z= new B();
        }
    }
}

class B{
//variables and methods
}
```

I want an Expression in if block of xyz() to check weather object z have assigned an instance of B or not where I've made comment in if block's bracket.
or in other way.

what is a way to check weather any java object have instance of their class or not?

Comment: by checking if it´s not `null`?

Comment: @KevinEsche I've tried this but it throws run time null pointer exception.

Comment: @AkshayPethani If you have tried it, Show the code. Maybe you made a mistake

Comment: @Jens you're right I've not initialized the object with null. By initializing object with null. Program run successfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using instanceof you can check this

Try this:

```
        B b= new B();
        B z = null; 
        if( z instanceof B){
           z=b;
           System.out.println("yes");
        } else{
           z = new B();
           System.out.println("no");
        }
```